# Impossible? Restoring/fixing a corrupted partition after updating Mojave?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, partitioning, backup

it seems that my main partition got corrupted and now I can't access it after updating to Mojave.

[image]

I ended up re-installing Sierra on my bootcamp partition (which is still accessible), but my main partition isn't working.

The partition in question:

2: 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC               825.0 GB   disk0s2

You can see that it doesn't show up in the Disk Utility GUI

[image]

Also the SSD got separated (this is supposed to be a hybrid drive).

Is there a solution for this OTHER THAN restoring from backup or formatting completely?

My backup hard drive also got corrupted.

Is this impossible to fix?

Bonus: TestDisk analysis update
[image]

Comment: Do you mean you cannot access it from within Mojave, or just from within older systems? The GUID is for an APFS partition, which is too new for Sierra to recognize anyway.

Comment: I can't access it on Sierra I believe.I think I was trying to restore Mojave because of a bug, then I might have restarted when the loading was taking too long and it stopped showing up. Thats when I restored to Sierra on a new partition

Answer (score 0):

The partition is not corrupted. It is using the [APFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System) filesystem format, which was added in High Sierra – older macOS versions will not recognize it (they only support the older HFS+).

To extract your data, either use the [Paragon APFS Retrofit Kit](https://www.cultofmac.com/530025/how-to-access-apfs-volumes-on-older-versions-of-macos/) (now discontinued, but still has a working [download link](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/9n43nj/does_anybody_have_a_copy_of_paragons_apfs/)), or use a more recent macOS version, or temporarily boot a Linux CD with `apfs-fuse` installed.

Comment: Thanks. How come recovery went back to Sierra? Is there a way to update the recovery partition in the future?